# SKSpriteNode will not center

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode

I have this inside my GameScene which is called in the didMove()

```
for i in 1...5 {

    // path to create the circle
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y), radius: CGFloat(((43 * i) + 140)), startAngle: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-50)), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: false)

    // the inside edge of the circle used for creating its physics body
    let innerPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y), radius: CGFloat(((43 * i) + 130)), startAngle: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-50)), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: false)

    // create a shape from the path and customize it
    let shape = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)
    shape.lineWidth = 20
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.99, blue:0.99, alpha:1.00)

    // create a texture and apply it to the sprite
    let trackViewTexture = self.view!.texture(from: shape)
    let trackViewSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: trackViewTexture)
    trackViewSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: innerPath.cgPath)
    self.addChild(trackViewSprite)

}
```

It uses UIBezierPaths to make a few circles. It converts the path into a SKShapeNode then a SKTexture and then applies it to the final SKSpriteNode.

When I do this, the SKSpriteNode is not where it should be, it is a few to the right:

[image]

But when I add the SKShapeNode I created, it is set perfectly fine to where it should be:

[image]

Even doing this does not center it!

```
trackViewSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

No matter what I try it just will not center.

Why is this happening? Some sort of bug when converting to a texture?

P.S - This has something to do with this also [Keep relative positions of SKSpriteNode from SKShapeNode from CGPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382469/keep-relative-positions-of-skspritenode-from-skshapenode-from-cgpath)
But there is also no response :(

Edit, When I run this:

```
let testSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellow, size: trackViewSprite.size)
self.addChild(testSprite)
```

It shows it has the same frame also:
[image]

Comment: My first guess would be the frame size changes,  when converting from shape to texture, you might be grabbing more than the size you think you are grabbing

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I should print the frame and see if it has the same size?

Comment: just make the background white when you show it as a sprite,  you should see more black than you expect

Comment: oh... put a black square on your SKShapeNode that fills the screen

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I am not able to set the background color of the texture, shape, or sprite. Maybe I misunderstood what you said? And what do you mean a black sqaure, like using the 'shape.frame' and create another shapenode with that frame to see? Thanks by the way, this problem has been really been bothering me

Comment: lol sorry,  I am tired,  what I told you wouldn't work,  Just add a yellow SKSpriteNode the size of the texture to your sprite, not shape.  `let test = SKSpriteNode(color:SKColor.yellow, size:sprite.size);spr.zPosition = -1; sprite.addChild(spr);`

Comment: Oh I totally missed that constructor. Alright, so from that is this: http://imgur.com/a/mMJE5. Seems like the frame size has the right width?

Comment: definitely not,  look at all that extra yellow on the side

Comment: you can specify the size of the texture you want to  grab from the view with let trackViewTexture = self.view!.texture(from: shape, crop:rect) https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/

Comment: Yeah, I tried that along with a ton of other stuff. Still same issue though, here is what I have now: `let trackViewTexture = self.view!.texture(from: shape, crop: shape.frame)!
   let trackViewSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: trackViewTexture)
            self.addChild(trackViewSprite)`

Comment: you can't use the shapes frame, it is calculating wrong,  you know the color sprite we made?  do that to the skskape just to see what its frame looks like.  You can't use the texture though, because it adds to the frame

Comment: Oh ok so I did what we did to the sprite but to the shape, `let testSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellow, size: shape.frame.size)` and it came out like this, http://i.imgur.com/rIxesug.png. So if I can't use the shape's frame, should I calculate it manually then?

Comment: why is it calculating so big

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125652/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-nicholas714).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long discussion, we determined that the problem is due to the frame size not being the expected size of the shape.

To combat this, the OP created an outer path of his original path, and calculated the frame that would surround this.  Now this approach may not work for everybody.

If anybody else comes across this issue, they will need to do these things:

> 1) Check the frame of the SKShapeNode to make sure that it is correct
>   2) Determine what method is best to calculate the correct desired frame
>   3) Use this new frame when getting `textureFromNode` to extract only the desired texture size

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this issue and solved it similarly to the accepted answer - but I noticed that it seems that node.calculateAccumulatedFrame() does not always calculate gaussian blurs correctly and will often clip the blur - which looks horrible. My solution -

1. make it square using largest dimension
2. if using blur increase largest dimension by 10% (not sure if this helps - something is clipping my blur in view?.texture(fromNode) )
3. clip against max size (view dimensions)

Sudo code:

```
let texBounds = shapeNode.calculateAccumulatedFrame()
var largestDim = max(texBounds.width, texBounds.height) * 1.1
let viewDim = max(view!.bounds.width, view!.bounds.height)
largestDim = min(largestDim, viewDim)
let cropBounds = CGRect(x: -1.0 * largestDim, y: -1.0 * largestDim, width: largestDim * 2, height: largestDim * 2)
let tex = view?.texture(from: alphaNode, crop: cropBounds)
texNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex)
```